# Doubt regarding the IN instruction

Tags: microprocessor

```
     When I write IN AL,80H ,how is 80H treated as an address?            
        Shouldn't it be IN AL,[80H] ?
```

(I've learned that in order to specify an address,square brackets are used).

Comment: Which processor? I'm assuming x86 but the "IN" instruction appears on other processors too.

Comment: Yes,yes the 8086

Comment: This is obviously processor-specific and probably assembler-specific.  Closing because without knowing the processor and assembler, any attempt to answer is a waste of time.  This really should have been obvious.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, it is inconsistent for the instruction set to not use brackets around the port number to indicate the indirection that is being used (i.e. that your 80h is the address of something, not the value to use directly).

You don't say which microprocessor this IN instruction is for. I imagine it's 8086.

The Zilog Z80 is consistent in using brackets around IN/OUT ports numbers. The equivalent instruction for it would be `IN A,(80h)`.

Answer (score 1):

For all intents and purposes, x86 I/O ports are just numbers. They don't really behave like addresses -- they can't be used to store data, and don't support most addressing modes. (You can refer to an I/O port using a register, but only if that register is `al`, `ax`, or `eax`.)

Comment: Thank you..So you mean that IN AL,80H implies that the content of the port specified by 80H is moved to AL?

Comment: But MOV AX,1342H implies that 1342H is moved to AX?

Comment: @Susan More or less, yes. A more exact way of putting it would be to say that `IN AL, 80h` makes the CPU read a word from port 80h and puts the result in AL. Unlike memory accesses, IO port reads can have side effects, so it's important to be precise.

Comment: As to the inconsistency between this and MOV -- also correct. The long and the short of it really is that `IN` and `OUT` are almost never used in modern systems, so nobody's bothered to fix it. (They're occasionally used in low-level OS and BIOS development, and that's about it.)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there are different assemblers who require a different syntax for the `IN` and `OUT` instructions on x86 CPUs.

Linux and Solaris (x86 versions) are quite similar operating systems. Both OSes are shipped with an assembler. In both cases the assembler shipped with the OS uses a syntax which is a bit different than Intel's standard:

```
Linux / Solaris    Intel standard
---------------    --------------
mov (0x80), %al    mov al, [80h]
mov $0x80, %al     mov al, 80h
mov (%si), %ax     mov ax, [si]
mov %si, %ax       mov ax, si
```

The `in` and `out` instructions however differ between the assemblers:

```
Linux            Solaris            Intel standard
-----            -------            --------------
in $0x80, %al    in (0x80), %al     in al, 80h
in %dx, %al      in (%dx), %al      in al, dx
out %al, $0x80   out %al, (0x80)    out 80h, al
out %al, %dx     out %al, (%dx)     out dx, al
```

If you leave out the brackets you'll get an error message when using the Solaris assembler; use the brackets and you'll get an error message using the (old) Linux assembler.

The binary code created by the assemblers is exactly the same, of course - the assemblers generate code for the 80x86 CPUs.

When comparing the syntax of the `in` and `out` instructions to the syntax of the `mov` instruction you can see that the developers of the Solaris operating system were obviously thinking like you:

A port is an address so the port number must be written in brackets.

The developers of the GNU assembler (shipped with Linux) as well as the Intel developers were thinking differently:

A port is something special (and not an address) so the port number is not put into brackets.

**The direct answer to your question**

It depends on the assembler you use if you have to write "80h" or "[80h]". Assemblers using the Intel standard use "80h" without brackets.